# How to get the element that not in collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongo-shell

let's say I have a collection with `{key:1},{key:2},{key:3}`

I have some array `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`

I want to get the elements that not in the collection.

in this example, it will print `4,5,6,7`

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$setDifference`,

- `$group` by null, to create an array of element in `elem`,
- `$project` create elem difference using `$setDifference`

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      elem: { $push: "$key" }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      elem: { $setDifference: [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], "$elem"] }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-3OchyGnkuw)

Comment: thank you that works, is it possible to add some filter before grouping?